# Почему при создании файла bundle.js создается main.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Почему при попытке создать файл bundle.js, в папке dist появляется main.js? Я же задал имя файла bundle.js при этом еще он и остается минифицированным, несмотря на то, что я прописал mode: 'development'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

Comment: Код нужно прикладывать текстом, а не картинками. Что именно вы запускаете? Покажите полный вывод, а не две последних строчки.

Comment: Что в src/index.js? Вообще main.js не похож на результат работы webpack

Comment: переправил вопрос с кодом, смотрите выше

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы запускаете webpack не в той папке (или наоборот положили конфиг-файл не в ту папку) и в итоге webpack вообще не считывает конфиг и собирает что-то со своими настройками по умолчанию

Comment: Вы приложили код который я и так видел (пусть и сломав глаза). А остальное?

Comment: я действительно положил конфиг не в ту папку, он находился внутри src. Теперь все работает